# Помогите настроить сдвиг блоков сверху вниз

Tags: html, jquery, css

В данном примере новы блоки дописывать в начале блока и отпускает их, а надо добавлять в самый конец и поднимать их вверх(привязка блоков к подвалу)

```js
for (let i=1; i<10; i++) {
    setTimeout( function timer(){
        $('.id').prepend('<div class="ee">'+i+'</div>');
    }, i*1000 );
}
```

```css
.id{
width:200px;
height:220px;
background:#464c74;
}
.ee{
width:160px;
height:20px;
margin-left:20px;
background:red;
margin-top:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="id"></div>
```

Comment: по тексту вопроса Вам нужно блоки ставить снизу вверх, а не сверху вниз как написано в заголовке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function timer() {
    $('.id').prepend('<div class="ee">' + i + '</div>');
  }, i * 1000);
}
```

```css
.id {
  width: 200px;
  height: 220px;
  background: #464c74;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-align-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.ee {
  width: 160px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="id"></div>
```

Comment: для правильного результата тогда уж append вместо prepend

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев можно и так. дело в том, что В вашем примере 10,9,8,7...1, а не 1,2,3,4...10, поэтому я посчитал, что Вам нужна такая же последовательность блоков.

Comment: спасибо большое, тут сложность возникла, если родитель больше по длине... они его пытаются заполнить в одну полосу, а надо в столбец

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев сделайте пример на [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) пожалуйста

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w6g4pcy5/  прижать столбик к правому краю

Comment: в один столбик *